# Passing in a three.js object into javascript

Tags: function, object, parameters, three.js

So basically, I am making a robot object in javascript using Three.js and am passing in the three.js scene variable object I am using to draw the robot parts through the array- for some reason, though, the scene object will not pass into the function (it won't draw)- Am I missing something about javascript functions?

```
function Robot(sc){
    this.sc=sc;

    var robtexture = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
        map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('tex/dmetal.png')
    });

    this.parts = [];

    var current;

    //make body

    current=new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.CubeGeometry(10,15,10), robtexture);

    this.parts.push(current);

    alert("hit");

    //make legs
}

Robot.prototype.draw = function() {
    for (x in this.parts){
        this.sc.add(x);
        alert("hit");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this works more like you intended:

```
Robot.prototype.draw = function() {
  for (x in this.parts){
    this.sc.add(this.parts[x]); // < - spot the difference :)
    alert("hit");
  }
}
```

Comment: Oh ok...so I thought that the x represented the actual objects like it does in regular Java- is that not the case?